# CFSpreadsheet borders for Merged Cells

Tags: coldfusion, formatting, cfspreadsheet

I searched around for this for awhile, so forgive me if there is an answer already.  I am having trouble applying borders to merged cells using CFSpreadsheet.  Below is some example code.

```
<cfscript>
newSS = SpreadsheetNew('Testing');      //Create Spreadsheet    

SpreadsheetMergeCells(newSS,1,1,1,9);
SpreadsheetAddRow(newSS,'Underline this Header');
SpreadSheetFormatCell(newSS,{bold=true,alignment='center',bottomborder='thin'},1,1);    

Spreadsheetwrite(newSS,expandpath('myTest.xls'),true);  //Write File
</cfscript>
```

What I would expect is the top cell to be underlined all the way across.  What I get is the top cell only underlined through column "A" and not underlined after.  Is there anyway around this or is this just a limitation of CFSpreadsheet??

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [POI FAQ's](https://poi.apache.org/faq.html#faq-N100E3), ie underlying library CF uses to generate spreadsheets, this is currently not supported (emphasis mine):

> *12. How do I add a border around a merged cell?*
>
> Add blank cells around where the cells normally would have been and
>   **set the borders individually for each cell**. We will probably enhance
>   HSSF in the future to make this process easier.

Probably the best you can do for now is to use [SpreadsheetFormatCellRange](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-functions/functions-s/spreadsheetformatcellrange.html) instead of SpreadSheetFormatCell:

```
SpreadsheetFormatCellRange ( newSS
                , {bold=true,alignment='center',bottomborder='thin'}
                , 1,1,1,9 );
```

Comment: Thank you!  That worked!  I hope they fix this in the future.  My users want this spreadsheet to come out so specific that I was trying everything to get borders to show.  The only weird thing is now the cells A-I are all really squished in this example, but I will work through that next :)

Comment: BTW that POI Faqs link gave me an error - not found :(

Comment: @vivasuzi - Thanks for the heads up about the links!  Mangled links now fixed ;-)

Comment: *now the cells A-I are all really squished in this example* Weird. Under CF11 the before and after cell size is the same.

Comment: We are on CF 10.  Wonder if that makes a difference. Thanks for your help!  We are now looking at some other things b/c it seems this method is a ton of extra work.  Since the formatted spreadsheet already exists, now we are trying some older methods we have used to just edit the data in the spreadsheet